# Twilio making web application crash

Tags: python, django, twilio

I am getting an unexpected error and am unable to find out the solution to my problem.When I am submitting the form on which I am getting the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 111, in get_response
    response = callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

  File "/home/ubuntu/django-apps/poive/apps/smsreminders/views.py", line 77, in cron_process_adherence_responses
    results =process_adherence_responses()

  File "/home/ubuntu/django-apps/poive/apps/smsreminders/utils.py", line 64, in process_adherence_responses
    date_sent=today)

  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/twilio/rest/resources.py", line 95, in inner_func
    return myfunc(*args, **kwargs)

  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/twilio/rest/resources.py", line 1041, in list
    return self.get_instances(params=params, **kwargs)

TypeError: get_instances() got an unexpected keyword argument 'date_sent'
```

Please help me to fix it

Comment: Hey anks!  Thanks for the question - would love to help getting your SMS reminders Django app working with Twilio.  Think you can edit your question to add the code that is throwing the error?